# Wifi does not work well on Lenovo Thinkstation P320

Tags: networking, drivers, lenovo

I just installed Ubuntu on a Lenovo Thinkstation P320. The wifi was working well on Windows. On Ubuntu, when I select my network and enter the password it just repeatedly asks me to enter the password. Presumably the connection is too weak to login.

Right now I'm connected via my phone which is literally next to the computer, so the default drivers appear to be good enough for that.

In case it's useful, here's some information on the connection:

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-LM [8086:15b7] (rev 31)
    DeviceName:  Onboard LAN
    Subsystem: Lenovo Ethernet Connection (2) I219-LM [17aa:103d]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried many things that did not work. The following simple fix did:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall network-manager
```